# How to avoid hardcode URL in Django view

Tags: django

I am working on a simple project on Django. Currently the views that I am implementing always return a hardcode path:

```
def temp_view(request):
   ...
   return render("app/detail.html")
```

or

```
def temp_view_2(request):
   ...
   return redirect("/app/view2")
```

What I want to do is to get rid of the hardcode URL (for view URL and the template URL). Is there a proper way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django provides a few different methods. In a view, the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()` function is most often used. A full discussion of this problem and the options provided by Django is here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: Thanks, this solve the second example (reverse the view URL by using the view name). How about the first example? It is a html file.

Comment: the reverse() function takes a path to the view as an argument, so it can be used for both cases. For example:
    case1: reverse('app.views.temp_view') and
    case2: reverse('app.views.temp_view2')
The path to the file on disk is not a URL, and cannot be "reversed", as any number of views may use that file.